# PBI generated query having a lengthy where clause which filter out certain records (Direct Mode)

Tags: powerbi, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, dax, directquery

We are creating PBI report with data sources in Direct Mode. Row level security has been implemented through some tables. While viewing the report with data security , we could see a lengthy where clause is included in the PBI generated back end query (Snowflake). It seems the where clause is containing values for each records of the result set, but sometimes here they miss certain records and we couldn't identify why those values are not included.

We tried using dynamic parameters and able to see the records are coming in the grid, but we couldn't go with parameters as there are some issues with RLS and multi selection.

Is there a solution to avoid generating the where clause in the back end query?

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: My bad , I missed the last part of the question. I am looking for a solution or workaround to get rid of the where statement which is generated by PBI.